# DMS alternative to Alfresco (document management)

Tags: document-library, document-management, dms, document-repository

What alternative DMS are there? What features do they offer?

What's about sharepoint? Is it worth mentioning?

Comment: not programming related (not even remotely)....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Open Source document management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system#Open_Source_document_management_systems) for a starter. Btw I'm not sure your question is anyhow programming related.

Comment: You are right, the question is very abstract. I'm searching for DMS which are easy extensible by individual software.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint is absolutly an option! I have work with both systems and SharePoint has some advantages due its high Office Integration (automatic checkout / version control / document meta data). For more information google windows sharepoint services / microsoft office sharepoint sever.

Often its an infrastructur question do you have a windows enviroment?

If you do some evaluation i think SharePoint should be in the race.

LiveLink is an other big player in ECM.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing an evaluation. I'll have a look at sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

IBM DB2 Content Management System - of course it's not open source and it's damn expensive :)

and I think Alfresco is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Open Source DMS solution around too. Nuxeo & Alfresco...